# Can a reviewer ignore a review due to lack of knowledge?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I found today this question: [Minor edit of code rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298123/minor-edit-of-code-rejected).

I was looking for a question when it is appropriate to edit a piece of code. I edited an answer, because I know this will not run because of a small mistake by the owner of the answer (but it wouldn't have changed the answer at all because the focus of the code were somwhere else but that's another story). What surprises me more is what the owner of the accepted answer wrote:

> Two, anyone moderating the edits may not know the language well enough to play "mental compiler" to make sure the before and after versions are exactly the same. To be honest, I didn't even know Rust was a thing until I read this question. If I saw that edit, I would have rejected it because I can't know if your edited code does exactly the same as the original. Better for those reviewing edits to err on the side of caution, especially for code edits.

So if I understood this correctly: Reviewers aren't able to ignore an edit. The only thing they can do is approve or reject an edit although they don't know anything about the language.

If that's the case why is that so? Woudln't it better for a reviewer to be able to ignore a suggested edit? Of course if that's already the case then I'm happy with it. I rather ask a stupid question than not asking.

Comment: No, you didn't understand it correctly,  or whoever wrote it was wrong. There is "Ignore" button for any review, plus reviewer can simply close the tab or navigate to a different page. Nothing is forcing anyone to approve or reject a suggested edit when they review it. That said, do not edit code.

Comment: You can "Skip" any review, including suggested edits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can a reviewer ignore a review due to lack of knowledge?

**Yes.**

There is a 'Skip' button for every review queue:

(I couldn't resist taking a screenshot of the suggested edit of a screenshot of a suggested edit:)

> [image]

Comment: Editception....

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was *literally* in the middle of doing that! http://i.stack.imgur.com/huf9j.png

Comment: lol your circle is thick and kind of rectangular... ;-) (but all good... :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Proof that it's freehand :P

Answer (score 4):

A reviewer can skip a review item, yes. Just press Skip.

The thing is through, there is a general rule that editing code is something you should try to avoid. A small change can have a huge impact and often we don't know exactly why a user wrote the code like that. Commenting on the answer is often considered better since that gives the author the chance to edit it in.

If you have earned the edit privilege you can edit without going through the review queue, so there is no direct judgement on your edit. Generally, if someone in the review queue sees an edit on code in an answer without very clear edit summary they will reject it. Just to prevent harm to the answer.

Comment: In a nutshell: Never edit a code. In what case should I edit a code?